# C# Marshal Slice with stride

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, marshalling

Is there a way to have a Span of 256 bytes divided as 8 elements (stride = 32bytes)? T is equal to 20 bytes so 12 bytes will be ignore.

By doing new Span(ptr, 64) the stride is equal to 4, because a int size is 4.

What I am looking for is on unity it is call NativeSlice.

Comment: What's wrong with `yourSpan.Slice(elementNum * 32, 32)`

Comment: Use an overlay.  You can use the offset property.  See following example which has an int and double at same offset : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshalling-classes-structures-and-unions#declaring-prototypes-2